# Setting a picture to "bleed" over parent md-content

Tags: angular-material

Had this working magically on an earlier version (but it broke almost everything else about the layout), but tI thought it was so COOL that I want to recreate it, but without breaking anything else.

So I have a logo (the one I use in this example is just one I borrowed on the internet). But lets say its the logo below:)

[image]

I want to use this one on the toolbar, but I want it to "bleed" over the cmd-content below AND above. Easy to get it to bleed to the below one, but how do I let it bleed on the above one? 
I created a JSfiddle to show the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/avbd0o2n/

```
<body>
    <md-content layout="column" class="filler" layout-fill id="page">
        <md-content id="topbleed" flex=10 class="filler" layout="row"></md-content>
        <md-content id="mid" class="filler" layout="row" flex>
            <md-content layout="column" class="filler sidebleed" flex="10" id="leftbleed"></md-content>
            <md-content layout="column" id="section4-5" flex>
                <md-toolbar id="toolbar" class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <img layout="row" layout-align="center center" src="http://cf067b.medialib.glogster.com/dimond-queen/media/f4/f4268cbbc332de67e0d2e49d30ee777f4e17845c/tumblr-mgj4rnf0jz1s1e931o1-400.png" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"/>
                    <span flex></span>
                    <md-button>
                        <span style="font-size: 150%;">A</span> A <span style="font-size: 75%;">A</span>
                    </md-button>
                </md-toolbar>
                <md-content id="section5 flex">
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at nibh sed libero tristique rutrum eu sed est. In a pulvinar risus, dictum faucibus magna. Suspendisse sed quam orci. Proin convallis finibus tortor, eget euismod dolor rutrum in. Nunc lacinia hendrerit massa eu pretium. Donec gravida placerat suscipit. Nam ut hendrerit enim. Donec lacinia ullamcorper diam, et tempus ligula iaculis lacinia. Duis blandit massa sapien, sed egestas nisi fermentum sed. Praesent aliquet, enim in vulputate maximus, risus ante eleifend magna, sed lobortis metus eros maximus justo. Etiam venenatis sem eu nisi tempor tempor. Proin dignissim metus eget interdum vulputate. Praesent iaculis metus ut lorem ornare tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                    </p><p>
                    Nunc porta laoreet turpis, in ullamcorper turpis suscipit nec. Integer molestie, mi lacinia accumsan sollicitudin, neque felis commodo dolor, interdum suscipit nisi lectus in ligula. Etiam tristique ullamcorper massa. Sed placerat felis at tortor vehicula, vitae ornare felis interdum. Vestibulum lacus velit, egestas vel ante sit amet, sodales vehicula ligula. Etiam auctor nibh tellus, a efficitur lectus porta eu. Suspendisse potenti. Cras placerat ligula orci, feugiat fringilla eros varius convallis. Pellentesque dolor erat, tristique lobortis imperdiet ac, condimentum id nulla. Duis vestibulum est vitae sodales tempor. Sed dictum accumsan rutrum. Pellentesque euismod ornare est a suscipit.
                    </p><p>
                    Curabitur nec ipsum hendrerit, lacinia diam in, placerat erat. Morbi hendrerit id est id mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin metus mauris, tincidunt eget dui at, luctus elementum metus. Aenean convallis tellus sit amet velit tempus, eget aliquet urna ultrices. Nam malesuada erat non felis egestas, eget ultrices diam elementum. Fusce eget ante ac urna fermentum molestie id eget nisi.
                    </p><p>
                    Curabitur eros diam, facilisis lobortis gravida ac, tincidunt et velit. Fusce suscipit, ex ut vulputate pretium, nisi ligula iaculis tellus, a ornare ex arcu at nisi. Suspendisse interdum iaculis eros, non ullamcorper dolor. Maecenas semper leo auctor malesuada eleifend. Quisque sit amet nunc eu metus faucibus condimentum finibus eu dolor. Quisque vel dui tincidunt, tristique diam eu, scelerisque lacus. In sit amet ipsum molestie, laoreet leo ac, bibendum urna. Sed id erat vitae lacus bibendum porta ac ut velit. In vel nunc tempus, laoreet ante a, dapibus tellus. Nunc fermentum arcu sed vulputate laoreet. Quisque magna ante, fermentum nec rhoncus non, pretium eget sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sem elit, volutpat eget ultrices in, iaculis at lorem. Sed lobortis felis lectus, eget auctor diam molestie eget.
                    </p><p>
                    Aliquam condimentum massa ut blandit interdum. Suspendisse varius ultrices quam a auctor. Mauris at ornare quam. Donec rutrum dictum scelerisque. Suspendisse finibus pulvinar odio, sit amet vulputate ipsum accumsan condimentum. Nulla at auctor neque, sollicitudin vehicula lacus. Curabitur tincidunt sagittis orci, vel imperdiet dui congue ut. Curabitur ac sapien ut dolor pharetra malesuada in lacinia metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur non suscipit enim. Phasellus in eros euismod, malesuada dolor sit amet, mattis sapien. Donec maximus libero vel est imperdiet, vel fermentum sapien rhoncus. Integer ultricies non sem nec facilisis. Ut gravida id quam quis finibus.
                    </p><p>
                    Maecenas vel neque laoreet, accumsan risus sed, sollicitudin sem. Fusce semper sapien ex, vitae posuere metus tempor id. Sed lacinia ex vel elit efficitur vestibulum. Praesent vitae dapibus ante. Curabitur suscipit nulla id feugiat finibus. Cras ut est ut neque vestibulum rutrum. Proin vel tristique velit. Morbi ut urna felis. Sed vitae tortor maximus est accumsan porta. Nunc ut dapibus justo, tincidunt suscipit ipsum. Aenean dapibus velit ut mollis efficitur.
                    </p><p>
                    Aenean in lorem suscipit ante elementum interdum. Donec pretium suscipit lacinia. Vestibulum quis ultricies elit. Donec condimentum sollicitudin neque. Etiam a viverra erat. Vivamus posuere volutpat magna, ac pellentesque elit vulputate at. Vestibulum in turpis eu turpis ullamcorper tristique vitae nec turpis. Curabitur vestibulum vehicula nisl, in vulputate neque vehicula in. Suspendisse dignissim, sem non rutrum iaculis, augue nisi aliquet urna, ac faucibus ligula risus vel mauris. Aenean sem justo, viverra nec tincidunt ac, mollis vehicula magna. Aenean eu mi dapibus, pulvinar felis in, maximus nisl. Nulla mollis purus eu viverra rutrum.
                    </p>
                </md-content>
            </md-content>
            <md-content id="rightbleed" flex=10 class="filler sidebleed"></md-content>
        </md-content>
    </md-content>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I sort of fixed it.
If the md-content and md-toolbar is on the same "level" it seems to work. So in the above example, if you move the md-content above into the same set of md-contents. It works (check out where topbleed ended up). Or:

```
    <md-content id="mid" class="filler" layout="row" flex>
        <md-content layout="column" class="filler sidebleed" flex="10" id="leftbleed"></md-content>
        <md-content layout="column" id="section4-5" flex>
    <md-content id="topbleed" flex=10 class="filler" layout="row"></md-content>
            <md-toolbar id="toolbar" class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <img layout="row" layout-align="center center" src="http://cf067b.medialib.glogster.com/dimond-queen/media/f4/f4268cbbc332de67e0d2e49d30ee777f4e17845c/tumblr-mgj4rnf0jz1s1e931o1-400.png" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"/>
                <span flex></span>
                <md-button>
                    <span style="font-size: 150%;">A</span> A <span style="font-size: 75%;">A</span>
                </md-button>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-content id="section5 flex">
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at nibh sed libero tristique rutrum eu sed est. In a pulvinar risus, dictum faucibus magna. Suspendisse sed quam orci. Proin convallis finibus tortor, eget euismod dolor rutrum in. Nunc lacinia hendrerit massa eu pretium. Donec gravida placerat suscipit. Nam ut hendrerit enim. Donec lacinia ullamcorper diam, et tempus ligula iaculis lacinia. Duis blandit massa sapien, sed egestas nisi fermentum sed. Praesent aliquet, enim in vulputate maximus, risus ante eleifend magna, sed lobortis metus eros maximus justo. Etiam venenatis sem eu nisi tempor tempor. Proin dignissim metus eget interdum vulputate. Praesent iaculis metus ut lorem ornare tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                </p><p>
                Nunc porta laoreet turpis, in ullamcorper turpis suscipit nec. Integer molestie, mi lacinia accumsan sollicitudin, neque felis commodo dolor, interdum suscipit nisi lectus in ligula. Etiam tristique ullamcorper massa. Sed placerat felis at tortor vehicula, vitae ornare felis interdum. Vestibulum lacus velit, egestas vel ante sit amet, sodales vehicula ligula. Etiam auctor nibh tellus, a efficitur lectus porta eu. Suspendisse potenti. Cras placerat ligula orci, feugiat fringilla eros varius convallis. Pellentesque dolor erat, tristique lobortis imperdiet ac, condimentum id nulla. Duis vestibulum est vitae sodales tempor. Sed dictum accumsan rutrum. Pellentesque euismod ornare est a suscipit.
                </p><p>
                Curabitur nec ipsum hendrerit, lacinia diam in, placerat erat. Morbi hendrerit id est id mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin metus mauris, tincidunt eget dui at, luctus elementum metus. Aenean convallis tellus sit amet velit tempus, eget aliquet urna ultrices. Nam malesuada erat non felis egestas, eget ultrices diam elementum. Fusce eget ante ac urna fermentum molestie id eget nisi.
                </p><p>
                Curabitur eros diam, facilisis lobortis gravida ac, tincidunt et velit. Fusce suscipit, ex ut vulputate pretium, nisi ligula iaculis tellus, a ornare ex arcu at nisi. Suspendisse interdum iaculis eros, non ullamcorper dolor. Maecenas semper leo auctor malesuada eleifend. Quisque sit amet nunc eu metus faucibus condimentum finibus eu dolor. Quisque vel dui tincidunt, tristique diam eu, scelerisque lacus. In sit amet ipsum molestie, laoreet leo ac, bibendum urna. Sed id erat vitae lacus bibendum porta ac ut velit. In vel nunc tempus, laoreet ante a, dapibus tellus. Nunc fermentum arcu sed vulputate laoreet. Quisque magna ante, fermentum nec rhoncus non, pretium eget sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sem elit, volutpat eget ultrices in, iaculis at lorem. Sed lobortis felis lectus, eget auctor diam molestie eget.
                </p><p>
                Aliquam condimentum massa ut blandit interdum. Suspendisse varius ultrices quam a auctor. Mauris at ornare quam. Donec rutrum dictum scelerisque. Suspendisse finibus pulvinar odio, sit amet vulputate ipsum accumsan condimentum. Nulla at auctor neque, sollicitudin vehicula lacus. Curabitur tincidunt sagittis orci, vel imperdiet dui congue ut. Curabitur ac sapien ut dolor pharetra malesuada in lacinia metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur non suscipit enim. Phasellus in eros euismod, malesuada dolor sit amet, mattis sapien. Donec maximus libero vel est imperdiet, vel fermentum sapien rhoncus. Integer ultricies non sem nec facilisis. Ut gravida id quam quis finibus.
                </p><p>
                Maecenas vel neque laoreet, accumsan risus sed, sollicitudin sem. Fusce semper sapien ex, vitae posuere metus tempor id. Sed lacinia ex vel elit efficitur vestibulum. Praesent vitae dapibus ante. Curabitur suscipit nulla id feugiat finibus. Cras ut est ut neque vestibulum rutrum. Proin vel tristique velit. Morbi ut urna felis. Sed vitae tortor maximus est accumsan porta. Nunc ut dapibus justo, tincidunt suscipit ipsum. Aenean dapibus velit ut mollis efficitur.
                </p><p>
                Aenean in lorem suscipit ante elementum interdum. Donec pretium suscipit lacinia. Vestibulum quis ultricies elit. Donec condimentum sollicitudin neque. Etiam a viverra erat. Vivamus posuere volutpat magna, ac pellentesque elit vulputate at. Vestibulum in turpis eu turpis ullamcorper tristique vitae nec turpis. Curabitur vestibulum vehicula nisl, in vulputate neque vehicula in. Suspendisse dignissim, sem non rutrum iaculis, augue nisi aliquet urna, ac faucibus ligula risus vel mauris. Aenean sem justo, viverra nec tincidunt ac, mollis vehicula magna. Aenean eu mi dapibus, pulvinar felis in, maximus nisl. Nulla mollis purus eu viverra rutrum.
                </p>
            </md-content>
        </md-content>
        <md-content id="rightbleed" flex=10 class="filler sidebleed"></md-content>
    </md-content>
</md-content>
```